# After Click Add to Cart Button then Button Change to Go to Cart in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, if-statement, shopping-cart

Please help me, i'm right now try to change Add to Cart Button to Go to Cart after click, how possible I can do that?, please help me, I have trying but didn't work, here my condition code in Controller:

```
if (Temporary::where('course_id','=', $request->IDCourse)->exists()) {
Session::flash('failed-session','Go to card');
}
else
{
Session::flash('failed-session','Add to cart');
}
```

and below my blade for looping product on cart box

```
@foreach($carts as $cart)
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item bg-light">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <input type="text" name="IDCourse" value="{{ $cart->course_id }}">
                <a href="{{ route('course.detail', $cart->course->id) }}" class="text-body">
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        @if($cart->course->image == '')
                            <img src="{{ asset('storage/courses/Default_Photo.png') }}" alt="" class="avatar-md square" />
                        @else
                            <img src="{{ asset('storage/courses/'.$cart->course->image) }}" alt="" class="avatar-md square" />
                        @endif
                        <div class="ms-3">
                            <h5 class="fw-bold mb-1">
                                {{ $cart->course->title }}
                            </h5>
                            <span class="fs-6 text-muted">
                                <span>{{ __('Oleh ') }}{{ $cart->course->user->name }}</span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<hr class="my-0">
@endforeach
```

And the last code to display the result from condition in controller

```
@if(Session::has('failed-session'))
<div class="alert alert-danger">
{{Session::get('failed-session')}}
</div>
@endif
```

I try `dd($request->course_id)` and displaying `null`. My planning is to check if customer have add to cart that item then the button change to Go to Cart. Please help me.Thank u so much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

simply just check this item in your controller then initialize the variable and check if variable is empty or not , then you can change the action of the form or change the src of the button ,
for example : if user->cart->count() > 0
redirect to the page
you can add another button for continue shopping as well too .

Comment: In this case, without redirect, i mean in the course detail page I have Button Add to Cart, so every customer who visits this detail course page will see Add to Cart button and after click that button then the button change to Go to Cart. as long as the product is still in the cart box the button always Go to Cart, this is similar with Udemy button. FYI the Customer can Add to Cart without login. So I looping data in the Cart box base on IP.

Comment: maybe its better to have a table that name called visitors 
insert the non registered users data in to it and when the user register or login in to your system just move all of those data to the main table .

Comment: Thank u for your suggestion bro. Much Appreciate.